# onPressed en ListWheelScrollView en Flutter

Tags: flutter, botón, listview, app, scroll

Estoy usando ListWheelScrollView para crear una lista de ElevatedButton, con la intención de que al tocar cada ElevatedButton, navegue a otra página. Lo intento usando  Navigator.push en onPressed, pero no me funciona.

Agradezco si alguien me puede indicar el error, y la mejor forma de solucionarlo.

Aquí dejo parte del código:

```
class _CardsDosState extends State<CardsDos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: ListWheelScrollView(
        itemExtent: 100,

        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        children: <Widget>[

          FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.8,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => BagreGrande()));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Bagre',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>( Colors.blueGrey),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desafurtunadamente en `ListWheelScrollView` no se puede hacer click en los hijos, aqui hay un problema habierto al equipo de flutter
[Prolema en github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803)